# Element of order 6 in A4

Tags: group-theory

How do I show that A<sub>4</sub> cannot have an element of order 6?

---

I'm not sure how to go about this. So, we would have to have the element either as (6 cycle)(1 cycle), (1 cycle)(6 cycle), (3 cycle)(2 cycle), and (2 cycle)(3 cycle). The first two are not possible because we only have 4 elements to per-mutate. The other two would lead it to be an odd permutation correct? How do I express this in a more formal way?

Comment: What are the elements of order $6$ is $S_4$ that you know?

Comment: What are the possible cycle-types of elements in $A_4$?

Comment: The cycles in the cycle-type of a permutation are to be disjoint. So there isn't enough room for a 2 cycle and a disjoint 3 cycle, for 2+3=5=one too many (and also an odd permutation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $\sigma \in \Sigma_4$ to be an element of order $6$. Decompose $\sigma$ into a product of cycles, remembering that the order of $\sigma$ is the l.c.m. of the order of its component cycles. Consider the possibilities and show that none of these gives rise to an element in $A_4$.

Comment: So, we would have to have the element either as (6 cycle)(1 cycle), (1 cycle)(6 cycle), (3 cycle)(2 cycle), and (2 cycle)(3 cycle).  The first two are not possible because we only have 4 elements to permutate.  The other two would lead it to be an odd permutation correct? how do I express this in a more formal way?

Comment: That's pretty formal. All that's left to do is justify why (3 cycle)(2 cycle) is an odd permutation, which isn't too hard.